# Error when starting spark job from idea - version issue ? java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: apache-spark

When starting the spark job from my idea, I get the following error : `java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD`

I understand from [this post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9219) that it might be a version conflict, however I don't know what is happening in my case

Starting the job with spark-submit work just fine. I'm using spark 2.0.0. Here is my sbt file

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
```

Job example :

```
object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Word2vec").master("spark://quentin:7077").getOrCreate()
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val input = sparkSession.read.text("/home/quentin/Downloads/wiki.fr.mini.text").as[String]
    input.flatMap(_.split(" ")).groupBy($"value").count().show()
  }
}
```

It is unclear to me what happens when launching a job from the idea. I understand that spark-submit send a jar to the master with all the dependancies required for the slaves to do the job but what happen when we just launch the main class ? How are the lib shipped and why do I get this error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the similar problem (using spark streaming on java). Solved by adding sparkConf.setJars(new String[]{"your-jar.jar"});